Use of past infinitive
I found an article with these sentences:

I want to have finished the job, before I go home.
You need to have passed the test, or else you won't be admitted.
Uh! You're supposed to have painted it blue, not pink!

They all look strange to me. When do we use past infinitive forms? When can we use them??

"I want to finish the job before I go home", "You were supposed to paint it blue." The middle one is OK, if the test was taken at some earlier time in the past.

https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=perfect+infinitive

@WeatherVane - I find all three perfectly OK.  'I want to [be in the situation of having finished] the job before I go home'.


(1) I want to have finished the job[,] before I go home.

The job is obviously not finished at the time of speaking.

(1') I want to finish the job[,] before I go home. is at least equally idiomatic, and uses simplification of tenses, always good when clarity isn't impaired.

....................................

(2) You need to have passed the test, or else you won't be admitted.

We don't know whether the addressee has actually passed the test; neither can we be sure that the speaker knows.
Again,

(2') You need to pass the test, or else you won't be admitted.

is available, and I'd say has a stronger implication that the addressee has not yet passed.
....................................

(3) Uh! You're supposed to have painted it blue, not pink!

Here, it is clear that 'it' has been wrongly painted pink.

(3') Uh! You're supposed to paint it blue, not pink!

is not wrong, but gives a strong impression that the (mis-)painting is still under way.

(3'') Uh! You were supposed to paint it blue, not pink!

means the same as (3) but is more idiomatic ... again, simplification of tenses/time-frame constructions.
